# Finding basis of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Without proof find the dimension and a basis of the following vector spaces $V$ over the given field $K$.
$V$ is the set of all polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ of degree at most $n$, in which the sum of
the coefficients is $0$; $K = \mathbb{R}$.

Can anyone enlighten me.

Comment: And what has been your attempt at solution?

Comment: I believe the set is v={x^n,x^n-1,...,1} I'm confused about the sum of all coefficients equals 0

Comment: Should be alpha infront of the x in all cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a $R_{n}[x]$ field. It's easy to see that it has dimension $n+1$ (determined by the coefficients of the polynom, not the degree of the polynom!). What happens if you have one equation that puts one of those coefficients in function of the others?

Comment: Here a little hint, more enlightening:
you have that $a_0+a_1+...+a_n=0$. Then you can do: $a_0=-a_1-a_2-...-a_n$. And then the vector space is determined by $n$ coefficients, because you can determine one in function of each others. So the dimension of the vector space is $n$, instead of $n+1$.

Comment: So do you get that there are n linearly independent vectors making up the basis?

Comment: Yes. Do you understand why?

Comment: Yes! The vector space is generated linear combinations of the $n$ coefficients of a polynom of $R_n[x]$. You have "one condition" on that subspace, that condition we can say that "takes one to $n+1$", so it remains $n$ free coefficients. If you had 2 conditions, you could be sure that it will be because the dimension is $(n+1)-2$. You have to be careful with that last part, because it's not always true, but you have to understand intuitively the idea of have a condition imposed on the vector space.

Comment: I think I understand why as the sum of the coefficients equal 0 we can generate one of the coefficients using the others meaning that one would be taking out in the sifting process so we would be left with n? Is that right? Also would in the question it says write the basis I'm not 100% sure what the concise answer would be for writing the actual basis. As I don't want to waffle and take up three quarters of a page

Comment: That's exactly the intuitive idea that I wanted you to see! For writing the basis, you can do that:

$a_0+a_1+a_2+...+a_n=0 \Rightarrow (-a_1-a_2-...-a_n)+a_1+a_2+...+a_n=0 \Rightarrow a_1\cdot(-1,1,0,...,0)+a_2\cdot(-1,0,1,0,...,0)+a_3\cdot(-1,0,0,1,0,...,0)+...+a_{n-1}\cdot(-1,0,...,0,1,0)+a_n\cdot(-1,0,...,0,1)$, so the vectors that form the basis you're looking for are:
$(-1,1,0,...,0),(-1,0,1,0,...,0),(-1,0,0,1,0,...,0),...,(-1,0,...,0,1,0),(-1,0,...,0,1)$.

Then, you have the coordinates of the polynoms that form the basis. The polynoms are:

$B={(-1,x),(-1,x^2),...,(-1,x^n)}$